# Is there a function to find a value in name value pair vector?

Tags: r, vector

Say there is a name value pair vector v

```
v <- c("NY"="New York", "MA"="Massachusetts")

names(v)
```

returns

```
"NY" "MA"
```

and

```
v["NY"]
```

returns

```
        NY 
"New York"
```

Is there a function to return "New York" only (no need to return NY in this case)?

Comment: Or `cat(v["NY"])` for unqoted result

Answer (score 2):

You could use `unname` which also works with multiple indices:

```
unname(v["NY"])
# [1] "New York"

unname(v[c("NY", "MA")])
# [1] "New York"      "Massachusetts"
```

Comment: @user2029709, no problem. If some answer solves your problem consider accepting and upvoting it as well as some answers to your previous questions, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If we are extracting a single element,  `[[` can do it without the `name`.

```
v[["NY"]]
#[1] "New York"
```

Or use `as.vector`

```
as.vector(v['NY'])
#[1] "New York"
```

which also works with multiple indices

```
as.vector(v[c('NY', 'MA')])
#[1] "New York"      "Massachusetts"
```